# Mvc dbSet<Reserva> não contem uma definição para getAll()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Criei este método, contudo aparece-me o erro descrito em cima, alguém sabe uma possível solução?

```
public IEnumerable<Reserva> GetBookingsByRoomId(int Id)
{
    HotelEntities db = new HotelEntities();
    var allBookings = db.Reserva.GetAll().ToList();
    var bookings = (from Quarto
                    in db.Quarto
                    where Quarto.ID_Quarto == Id
                    select Quarto
                   ).ToList();
    return Mapper.Map<List<Reserva>, List<Reserva>>(bookings);
}
```

Comment: mas qual e o erro que aparace?

Comment: `var allBookings = db.Reserva.GetAll().ToList();`  onde tenho getall()... ele diz-me que o dbSet<Reserva> nao contem uma definição para getAll()...

Comment: dentro desse HotelEntities tem o metodo getall?

Comment: Se ainda houver necessidade, achei agora também:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32855426